# Access to SparkContext from worker

Tags: apache-spark

I had the same issue as this :
[Distributed loading of a wide row into Spark from Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120257/distributed-loading-of-a-wide-row-into-spark-from-cassandra?answertab=votes#tab-top)

unfortunately I can't comment and ask how it works ... so I ask a new question.

I want to apply the same solution but ... I can't access to the "sc" (SparkContext) within the method map (Worker side). It's always null ... which I understand (not the same jvm). So I don't understand how this example could work for him with a cluster configuration.

I need to do exactly the same.

Thx

Comment: It would help if you'd post the code where you're having the issue.

Comment: according to this you can't: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spark-users/rkVPXAiCiBk

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my answer. I thought the list he had for keys was a RDD. But it is a list on the driver side and the map method is not the "RDD" method but the scala one. Therefore sc can be accessed !

Comment: It seems like solution to the problem you had, but not a solution to the question you've been asking about sparkContext and worker. it is better to put your insight as a comment on the question above.