# How do you query cassandra for a set of keys?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, cql

Given a set of primary keys (including the partition and clustering keys), what is the more performant way to query those rows from cassandra?

I am trying to implement a method that, given a list of keys, will return a spark RDD for a couple of other columns in the CF.  I've implemented a solution based on this question [Distributed loading of a wide row into Spark from Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120257/distributed-loading-of-a-wide-row-into-spark-from-cassandra) but this returns an RDD with a partition for each key.  If the list of keys is large this will be inefficient and cause too many connections to cassandra.

As such, I'm looking for an efficient way to query cassandra for a set of primary keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest solution should be grouping them by partition key using **IN** operator (or **>** if possible) for clustering keys and then, if needed, splitting these "supersets" client side.

Cheers,
Carlo

Comment: So if you had a key that looks like PRIMARY KEY ((part_col_1, part_col_2), cluster_1), how would you query that using the IN operator.  As I understand it, only part_col_2 could be queried using IN.

Comment: You should apply in operator only on clustering key ... so if you have many keys with same (part_col_1, part_col_2) and different cluster_1 ... cluster_N I would make 1 query select * from table where part_col_1 = "..." and part_col_2 = "..." and cluster_1 in ('a','b','c' ...) --- this will hit only one specific partition avoiding excessive cassandra stress on multiple nodes